# Nodejs and express using session data not stored in Firefox ,chrome browser its working fine

Tags: node.js, session, firefox

Session issue for Firefox using NodeJS and express

## My config

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'test',
proxy: true,
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
```

}));

## Session set(login function)

```
req.session.userid = result[0].userid;
```

req.session.username = result[0].username;
console.log(req.session);

Node version:10.15.1
Express Version :4.16.4

login function user data stored to session.
after login redirect to dashboard page session data to be cleared .
i will print session but data is empty.this issue only for firefox browser.any friends face similar issue? and needed solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

cache: false,
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true //all AJAX requests should include Cookie data
},

try this in your ajax session issue completed